# "end" as verb in sentence "President Lincoln hoped that slavery would end when he gave the Gettysburg Address."

Tags: word-usage, verbs, verb-forms, subjunctives

> President Lincoln hoped that slavery would end when he gave the Gettysburg Address.

In this sentence **hoped**, **end** and **gave** are verbs. I don't understand how **end** is treated as a verb. It is not performing any action, nor helping any verb nor it seems linking. Is it an **Action**, **Helping**, or **Linking** verb? If so, how?

Comment: I was given advice: "In English, you can verb any noun, if you want to". :-) Funny part is that noun "verb" is in a role of verb in this sentence.

Comment: This craziness ends here.

Comment: All's well that ends well

Comment: Have a look at "to end" (verb) in Oald.  Actually I don't understand your problem with the verb end. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/end_2

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "end" as used there as an active verb. Combined with the helping verb "would", it expressed the hoped-for (but at that time not yet realized) action of slavery *ending* (stopping, ceasing to exist).

Compare: "This class will end at 11am."

By the way, Lincoln had no illusion that slavery would end "when he gave the Gettysburg Address". The Civil War was far from over. Rather, *when he gave the Gettysburg Address* (and before, and after) he hoped that slavery would end sometime soon.

Answer (score 3):

It absolutely can be used as a verb. Things can end; this is an action.

> **End (verb)**: come or bring to a final point; finish.

Some examples:

> The war ended when Germany surrendered.
>
> The path ends at the road.
>
> I want to end my subscription.